# JaCoCo coverage is missing

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I've been working on this for hours, and every solution I've tried that I've found online makes no difference.

I have a project which is written in Kotlin. I have the Kotlin plugin installed on my sonar server. I am using JaCoCo plugin to generate code coverage report for sonar.

My project is multi-module, but only 1 sub-module has unit tests, and so I have defined my JaCoCo plugin there.

I am also using the Surefire plugin.

Here are my properties in my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <sonar.java.binaries>target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.language>kotlin</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.verbose>true</sonar.verbose>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportsPath>target</sonar.jacoco.reportsPath>
    <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>

    <surefireArgLine/>
</properties>
```

Here is my surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And here is my JaCoCo plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After running my unit tests, I generate my sonar report like so:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectName=vqs -Dsonar.projectKey=vqs
```

And Sonar reports no coverage.[image: sonar report summary]

At one point in time, I was getting code coverage data. At this time, the project was a single module, and was potentially not using surefire (I can't remember for sure).

Hoping somebody will see my error and help me out!

Thanks,
Tonya

EDIT, adding console output:

```
tohrel@ussd-olm-016438:~/projects/project-name-redacted/vqs-api$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectName=vqs -Dsonar.projectKey=vqs
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Variant Query Service - API 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) @ vqs-api ---
[INFO] User cache: /Users/tohrel/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.2.1
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Publish mode
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=143ms
[INFO] Server id: AWT2VY5OzSeF07PuEM-H
[INFO] User cache: /Users/tohrel/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load/download plugins
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=82ms
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=132ms
[INFO] Loaded core extensions:
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=140ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=63ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=618ms
[INFO] Load metrics repository
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=19ms
[INFO] Project key: vqs
[INFO] Project base dir: /Users/tohrel/projects/project-name-redacted/vqs-api
[INFO] -------------  Scan vqs
[INFO] Load server rules
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=178ms
[INFO] Base dir: /Users/tohrel/projects/project-name-redacted/vqs-api
[INFO] Working dir: /Users/tohrel/projects/project-name-redacted/vqs-api/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: src/main
[INFO] Test paths: src/test
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Language is forced to kotlin
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 254 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for kotlin: Sonar way
[INFO] Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin]
[INFO] 208 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin] (done) | time=2693ms
[INFO] 208/208 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=4ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=90ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] 57 files had no CPD blocks
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 151 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 484ms, dir size=658 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 582ms, zip size=444 KB
[INFO] Analysis report generated in /Users/tohrel/projects/project-name-redacted/vqs-api/target/sonar/scanner-report
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 27ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=vqs
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWVagYWzPCQMqzjb5q73
[INFO] Task total time: 7.582 s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.536 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-20T20:22:42-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 56M/869M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably this question here can be deleted after reading  https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarkotlin-code-coverage/1269 and https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarkotlin-plugin-1-0-1-broken-no-code-coverage/1732 ?

Comment: Thanks @Godin I have documented proof that it was working in June and July. Some change happened in early August that caused it to stop working. Several things changed during that time, but our use of Kotlin is not one of them. We have been using it since the beginning of the project. So I am skeptical that a bug in the Kotlin plugin is the cause, given that we saw it working previously.

I did try the sonar-jacoco plugin that is suggested as a fix in the second link, however... and it did not make any difference.

Comment: I also tried using an unofficial plugin: https://github.com/arturbosch/sonar-kotlin.

Still no coverage data. In my case I think there is something else I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: First of all - `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` and `sonar.jacoco.reportsPath` (first deprecated in favor of second) are properties of Java plugin, which can't and doesn't import `exec` for Kotlin, however you're forcing language of your project to be Kotlin by `sonar.language=kotlin`. Second - as per https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` should be for example `target/jacoco.exec` but not just `target`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With help from @Godin in his comments above (thank you very much) I have code coverage working.

This may not be the only solution, but it is one that works for me.

First, I removed the official sonar-kotlin-plugin from my extensions/plugins directory, and added instead this one: https://github.com/arturbosch/sonar-kotlin

Second, I updated my properties, which seemed to be out of date, to resemble what is outlined in this sample: https://github.com/akquinet/kotlin-calculator/blob/master/pom.xml

Properties (excerpt)

```
<properties>
    <!-- Sonar configuration -->
    <jacoco.report.ut>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.report.ut>
    <jacoco.report.it>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.report.it>

    <sonar.language>kotlin</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.junit.reportPaths>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${jacoco.report.ut},${jacoco.report.it}</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
</properties>
```

Plugin configs for surefire, failsafe, and jacoco

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-agent-ut</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${jacoco.report.ut}</destFile>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-agent-it</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${jacoco.report.it}</destFile>
                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Perfect really appreciate the details works like a charm now.